# Probability question for horse racing

Tags: probability, statistics

I know there is quite a few of these, but for some reason I have so much trouble understanding probability properly, so was hoping to get some help.

Basically there are 8 horses racing, assuming they are all equal, I would assumed they have a 1/8 chance of placing in any particular value (first, second, third etc).

My first question is, assuming that I want to figure out the chance of placing within the top 4. Can I do (1/8)+(1/8)+(1/8)+(1/8) = 4/8 or 50 percent chance of placing on the top 4?

Second question is if I had two horses, what would be there chance of placing on the top 4? This I'm a little confused what to do, partly because I know if one horse places, that means the second horse only has a 1/7 chance of placing the other numbers? So I would guess you have 4/8 for horse 1 and also (1/7)+(1/7)+(1/7)+(1/7) = 4/7 for horse 2?

So that would get a (4/8)*(4/7) = 28.6 percent chance of both horses getting on the top four?

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Thank you everyone, this was all so helpful for me :D!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there aren't any hidden horse dependencies, your approach to the first question is right.  Any given horse has a $4/8 = 1/2$ chance of placing in the top half.

As far as the second question is concerned, it's easiest to consider the probability of *neither* horse finishing in the top half.  Horse A finishes in the bottom half with probability $1/2$; horse B then finishes in one of the three remaining bottom half spots with probability $3/7$.  Therefore, both finish in the bottom half with probability $1/2 \times 3/7 = 3/14$, so at least one of them finishes in the top half with probability $1-3/14 = 11/14$.

There is a more systematic way to approach these questions, using the binomial coefficients.  We write $\binom{n}{k}$ (read "$n$ choose $k$"), to denote the number of ways to choose $k$ objects (order unimportant) out of $n$.  So if we have two horses, and we want the probability that they both finish in the bottom half, we find the number of ways for them to finish in two of the bottom four spots, and divide that by the number of ways for them to finish in any spots:

$$
\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}
$$

The expansion for the binomial coefficients is $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, where $n! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n$.  That gives us $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ and $\binom{8}{2} = 28$, so the probability of them both finishing in the bottom half is $6/28 = 3/14$, as before.

ETA: If the desired probability is that *both* horses fall in the top half, that's equal to the probability that both of them fall in the bottom half—the halves being indistinguishable from that perspective—or, again, $3/14$.

Comment: To be fussy, I think you mean 'using binomial coefficients' not "using the binomial distribution.'

Comment: Doggone it, you are quite right.  I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks that makes so much more sense, the only bit I'm having a bit of trouble on is the last part, I get the 3/14 becomes probability for both horses, but I don't get the 1-3/14, is that the rest of the fraction becomes just the one horse?

Comment: No, that means that if the probability that both horses fall in the bottom half is $3/14$, then the probability that at least one does *not* fall in the bottom half is one minus that, or $11/14$.  Alternatively, the probability that both horses fall in the *top* half is the same as that for both falling in the bottom half, or $3/14$.

Comment: Thanks dude you're amazing!!

Comment: Hi @BrianTung Thanks for your help, just a quick question when looking at it. I'm a bit confused in the 1 minus part. So just from thinking of it, wouldn't it be 3/14*2 since it has the chance of both horses falling in both the bottom and the top, and 1-3/14*2 would be the probability?

I guess what I'm confused with is why its only 1-3/14 and not 1-2*(3/14) Thanks!!

Comment: Both horses fall in the top half with probability $3/14$; they both fall in the bottom half with probability $3/14$; and they fall one in the top half, one in the bottom half with probability $4/7$.  This can be worked out as follows.  Call the horses P and Q.  P falls in the top half with probability $1/2$; Q then falls in the top half with probability $3/7$ and bottom half with probability $4/7$.  Thus both in the top half with probability $(1/2)(3/7) = 3/14$ and P in the top, Q in the bottom with probability $(1/2)(4/7) = 2/7$. (to be continued)

Comment: P falls in the *bottom* half with probability $1/2$; Q then falls in the top half with probability $4/7$ and the bottom half with probability $3/7$.  Thus both in the bottom half with probability $(1/2)(3/7) = 3/14$, and P in the bottom half, Q in the top half with probability $(1/2)(4/7) = 2/7$.  Thus, P and Q split halves with probability $2/7 + 2/7 = 4/7$.

Comment: THANK YOU!! YOU'RE A LEGEND MATE!! I UNDERSTAND IT NOW :DDDD

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first question is correct.
As for the second question, you can consider it in this way:
(1) The decided "top 4" group should be preliminary condition. You just have to assign the placing of the 2 particular horses to the "top 4" group. The number of the ways to do this is: $\displaystyle _4P_2$.
(2) The rest 6 horses could be any rest placing, so the number of assigning the 6 horses is: $\displaystyle 6!$.
(3) The total number of all 8 horses placing is: $\displaystyle 8!$.

Hence, the possibility of the 2 particular horses to hold the top 4 group is: $\displaystyle \frac{_4P_2 \times 6!}{8!}=\frac{3}{14}$.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes, you are correct. I will modify my answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Why do you mean "top 2"? I mean, pick up 2 places from "top 4", it's $_4P_2$.

Comment: Right, top four. Sorry. But @BrianTung took the question to mean at least one of two in the top four. So did I on first reading. You may be right, the translation is not so good. Is it 'there' or 'their'? With your interpretation, isn't it simply $(4/8)(3/7)$?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes, indeed it's simpler to think it in (4/8)(3/7), which is calculated using probability, not numbers of ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicting interpretations of the second question. See earlier answers and comments. Here is a brief simulation of 100,000 such races that includes both interpretations.

```
 h = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0);  m = 10^5;  t4 = numeric(m)
 for(i in 1:m) {
    x = sample(h, 4);  t4[i] = sum(x) }

mean(t4 == 2)  # both of my horses in top four
## 0.2156
mean(t4 >= 1)  # at least one in top four
## 0.78658
3/14; 11/14     # exact
## 0.2142857
## 0.7857143
```

This can also be solved with a 
**hypergeometric random variable** $X$ counting the number of my horses
among the top 4, chosen at random from a group in which 2 of the horses
are mine and 6 are not. Results below are for $P(X = 1)$ and $P(X = 2).$ I will leave it to you to look at the formula for the
PDF of the hypergeometric distribution.

```
 dhyper(1:2, 2,6,  4)      # exactly 1 or exactly 2 of my horses in top 4
 ##  0.5714286 0.2142857
 14*dhyper(0:2, 2,6,  4)
 ## 3 8 3
```